# Relation between pointers and arrays

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault

I was pretty sure that `*(pointer+1) = pointer[1]`.

My problem is that when i run this code:

```
  if (NULL == (*str_array = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*10))) {
    return ERROR;
}

splitter = strtok(str, TOKEN);


 while(splitter != NULL){

     if (NULL == ((*str_array )[i] =(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(str) +1))){
         return ERROR;

     }

     strcpy((*str_array )[i], splitter);


     splitter  = strtok(NULL,TOKEN);
     i++;
 }
```

i get  a `valgrind` output that says i got no leak or errors to suppress. The program works perfectly.

But when i replace `(*str_array )[i]` by `**(str_array + i)` and run 
`valgrind --leak-check=full ./program` i get the following output:

```
    ==18873== Invalid write of size 8
==18873==    at 0x1089B7: split_func (in /home)
==18873==    by 0x108B4E: main (in /home)
==18873==  Address 0x3100414747504724 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==18873== 
==18873== 
==18873== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==18873==  General Protection Fault
==18873==    at 0x1089B7: split_func (in /home)
==18873==    by 0x108B4E: main (in /home)
==18873== 
==18873== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18873==     in use at exit: 130 bytes in 3 blocks
==18873==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 1 frees, 1,154 bytes allocated
==18873== 
==18873== 11 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 3
==18873==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18873==    by 0x1089B6: split_func (in /home)
==18873==    by 0x108B4E: main (in /home)
==18873== 
==18873== LEAK SUMMARY:
==18873==    definitely lost: 11 bytes in 1 blocks
==18873==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18873==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18873==    still reachable: 119 bytes in 2 blocks
==18873==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18873== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==18873== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==18873== 
==18873== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18873== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

For everyone to know, "str" is a string to be split in every ","(TOKEN) and "splitter" the char pointer to do it so. "str_array" is a char *** pointer that is received as a parameter, and it´s supposed to be a dynamic array of dynamic strings.
The only difference bewteen both runs, is the one change i made in the code mentioned before. Can someone tell me what´s going on here?

Comment: pls rethink your tags... are you coding c or c++? it is a important difference

Comment: `(*str_array)[i]` is equal to `*(*str_array + i)`

Comment: `free` is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was pretty sure that `*(pointer+1)` = `pointer[1]`.

Yes. Those two expressions are equivalent for any array or pointer.

> But when i replace `(*str_array )[i]` by `**(str_array + i)` ...

Those two expressions are not equivalent.

`(*str_array )[i]` is `*(*str_array ) + i)`

`**(str_array + i)` is `*str_array[i]`